# Raspberry Pi camera not working

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, raspi-config

I bought a Raspberry Pi camera. Yesterday it worked perfectly but today am getting an error when I type:

```
raspistill -v -o test.jpg
```

The error I get is:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

Answer (score 1):

`ENOSPC` is an error code indicating "no space left on device".  This presumes it's being used appropriately by the application, but presumably it is.

If so then chances are you've filled the partition with your current working directory.  Note that 5% of it may be reserved for privileged purposes, so it may only look 95% full (try `df`).

Answer (score -2):

type in sudo before your command.... that should do the trick

Comment: If it was working yesterday, why would the OP need to type sudo today?

Comment: If it is because the partition is full (ENOSPC implies it is), and 5% was reserved for root only (by default it would be), then this may actually make a difference, but it is a bad idea.